# How do I specify from a date to the last occurence of a day in a specific month, using iCal?

Tags: icalendar

I want to make an event the happens yearly from the 1st of November through to the Fourth Thursday of November, using iCal. Is there support for this in iCal? How would I solve this?

This is what I have so far:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20151101
DTEND;BYDAY=DATE:20151126
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;
DESCRIPTION:Event description...
LOCATION:Event location...
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Event name
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
```

Edit: For clarity, I should add that I want to import this into Google Calendar, so any solution should be compatible by importing the .ics file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do that with a rule. Instead, you'll need to create a yearly event, with overrides for each year, precalculating when `DTEND` should be.

You can do this by creating additional `VEVENT` components that share the same `UID` as the first (which is missing from your example, this is not good!), and a `RECURRENCE-ID` specified.

Comment: I am not familiar with UID and RECURRENCE-ID. I will read through the [docs](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/), but could you give an example?

Comment: If you want an example, just try to create this event from a calendar client and then export it.